# What can I use to execute a function before leaving page on chrome?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Hi,

this works on firefox but not on chrome:

```
   $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "logout.php",
        async: false,
        data: { userid : 34 }
    });
});
```

is there any cross-browsing alternative out there?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to guarantee it will make it, hence why we have serverside sessions. Must stink when a person refreshes the page they get logged out. :)

Comment: the best way for doing that is by using websocket

Comment: on firefox it always works but on chrome it NEVER does.

Comment: try to write the listener in native js like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) it may work

Comment: Chrome wants the user's experience to be quick. So they kill open requests

Comment: @Joseph That is not going to make any difference.

Comment: maybe there is a problem with jquery compatabiltiy

Comment: I need the page logout.php executed because its a chat so if the user navigates away it MUST logout otherwise they will appear as they are still online.

Comment: @CainNuke if this a chat app so it you definitely use web socket for that

Comment: web socket? Well, I will have to do some research. Thanks.